# Extended Regular Expression: Find a Word That is Not Part of Another Word

Tags: regex, unix, grep

I am trying to search for words in a file using egrep. I am limited to `egrep` and cannot add a `-v` option so I must do it through the pattern.

**Example file**

```
... blah
blah foo blah
blah foobar blah
bhah_foobaz_blah
blah ...
```

**Desired output**

```
blah foo blah
bhah_foobaz_blah
```

I want to find every line containing an instance of `foo` that is not part of the word `foobar`.

From what I could find so far I thought it would be something like this, but it returns nothing:

```
egrep -i 'foo+^((?!bar).)*'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perl regexes support [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), the `(?!)` feature you tried to use. It's the ideal way to express the idea of "foo but not foobar".

```
grep -P 'foo(?!bar)'
```

If you're limited to POSIX extended regular expressions there is no equivalent feature. It's possible but quite convoluted to look for a non-match without negative lookaheads.

One way to do it is to check character by character at what follows `foo`. The next character is either

1. End of string (`$`)
2. Any character except "b" (`[^b]`)
3. A "b" (`b`)

If it's either of the first two cases you're done, it's a match. If it's a `b` then you have to check the character following the `b` using the same three-part pattern. The pattern looks like `$|[^b]|b(...)` where the `...` represents a nested pattern. Putting all the nested patterns together you get:

```
grep -E 'foo($|[^b]|b($|[^a]|a($|[^r])))'
```

Comment: That negative lookahead would be great if I could use it. Unfortunately I'm stuck with the grep -E option. But your solution for that did work so I am Thankful! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for

```
egrep '\bfoo\b'
```

which matches word boundaries

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It was correct for the way that I had incorrectly worded my question. I have since reworded my question because I want to find 'foo' everywhere, just not when its next to 'bar'